# util.promisify and promisifying functions via destructing

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to do a one liner that combines destructing and promisifying?

I'd like to promisify the following function on the spot (imagine that I am destructing several functions and wanting to promisify them all).

```
const { exec, example_of_another_function } = require('child_process');
```

The only way I can think of if splitting it up into two lines:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const example_of_another_function = util.promisify(require('child_process').example_of_another_function);
```